# internet explore zoom on hover and z-index

Tags: css, internet-explorer, hover, zooming, z-index

I need to zoom on hover some images in a webpage. To do it I used this CSS:

```
span.dropt {

}
span.dropt:hover {
    z-index: 6;
}
span.dropt span {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
    margin: 4px 0 0 0px;
    padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:black;
    border-width:1px;
    z-index: 10;
}
span.dropt:hover span {
    left: 40%;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    z-index:20;
}
```

The problem is that using an old version of ie the zoomed image go above the non-zoomed.

Have you got any suggestions?
Thanks a lot